# selecting next n elements having class foo

Tags: jquery

How to select next n hidden elements that have class "foo" using jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boldewyn's answer works, but `filter` is unnecessary. This also selects only hidden elements:

```
$(this).nextAll('.foo:hidden:lt('+n+')')
```

Comment: +1 I missed the 'hidden' part of the question on first scan too.

Answer (score 2):

Using [nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$(this).nextAll().filter('.foo:hidden:lt('+n+')');
```

The `:lt()` selector selects the next `n` elements, the `:hidden` selector hidden inputs.

Comment: Can you add `:hidden` to pick hidden inputs (as per OP's request)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).nextAll('.foo:hidden').filter(':lt('+n+')')
```